# How to include google test in visual studio code MinGW project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, googletest

I'm working on a Visual Studio Code project on Windows and i want to use Google Test. I'm able to include the header file only when i try to build the project i get multiple undefined references that can bee seen in the error list below.

I've installed Google Test to C:\googleTest. Then i ran the following commands inside the folder:

```
cmake .
cmake --build .
navigated to the googletest\googletest\gtest.sln 
And build this with the help of Visual Studio i build the solutions by pressing build all under build menu.
```

What i've tried:
i've added the following in my task.json args.

```
                "-l",
                "gtest",
                "-l",
                "gtest_main"
```

which resulted in this error:

```
> Executing task: ""C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe" -g "C:\Users\melvin.wiegman\OneDrive - Fourtress\Cursus\Design Patterns in Modern C++\Singleton\TestProblemSingleton\*.cpp" -o "C:\Users\melvin.wiegman\OneDrive - Fourtress\Cursus\Design Patterns in Modern C++\Singleton\TestProblemSingleton\.vscode\myProgram.exe" -I C:/Boost/include/boost-1_73 -I C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include -I C:/GoogleTest/googletest/bin -l gtest -l gtest_main" <

C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgtest
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgtest_main
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /d /c ""C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe" -g "C:\Users\melvin.wiegman\OneDrive - Fourtress\Cursus\Design Patterns in Modern C++\Singleton\TestProblemSingleton\*.cpp" -o "C:\Users\melvin.wiegman\OneDrive - Fourtress\Cursus\Design Patterns in Modern C++\Singleton\TestProblemSingleton\.vscode\myProgram.exe" -I C:/Boost/include/boost-1_73 -I C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include -I C:/GoogleTest/googletest/bin -l gtest -l gtest_main"" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

It seems it can't correctly find the google test library, but i don't know if this is because i forgot an include somewhere or maybe a step that i'm not aware of?

Can somebody tell me how to correctly add google test to my project and explain to me wat i'm doing wrong with the includes?

Error List:

```
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test::TestBody()':
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&) const'
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:66: undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:56: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GetTestTypeId()'
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:56: undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `RUN_ALL_TESTS()':
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:2486: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:2486: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(char const*, int)':
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:529: undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:529: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)'
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:529: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:529: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<testing::Test>::GetTearDownCaseOrSuite(char const*, int)':
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:550: undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:550: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)'
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:550: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:550: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<int, int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:1546: undefined reference to `testing::AssertionSuccess()'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int, int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:1529: undefined reference to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV44RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test[_ZTV44RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test]+0x20): undefined reference to `testing::Test::SetUp()'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV44RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test[_ZTV44RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test]+0x28): undefined reference to `testing::Test::TearDown()'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test::~RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test()':
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:56: undefined reference to `testing::Test::~Test()'
C:\Users\MELVIN~1.WIE\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0Ew4Pg.o: In function `RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test::RECORDFINDERTESTS_SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST_Test()':
C:/Users/melvin.wiegman/OneDrive - Fourtress/Cursus/Design Patterns in Modern C++/Singleton/TestProblemSingleton/main.cpp:56: undefined reference to `testing::Test::Test()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /d /c ""C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe" -g "C:\Users\melvin.wiegman\OneDrive - Fourtress\Cursus\Design Patterns in Modern C++\Singleton\TestProblemSingleton\*.cpp" -o "C:\Users\melvin.wiegman\OneDrive - Fourtress\Cursus\Design Patterns in Modern C++\Singleton\TestProblemSingleton\.vscode\myProgram.exe" -I C:/Boost/include/boost-1_73 -I C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include -I C:/GoogleTest/googletest/bin"" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

My project files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#define GTEST_LANG_CXX 1
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
using namespace std;

class SingletonDatabase
{
    SingletonDatabase()
    {
        cout << "INIT DATABASE\n";
        ifstream ifs("capticals.txt");
        string s, s2;

        while (getline(ifs, s))
        {
            getline(ifs, s2);
            int pop = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s2);
            capitals[s] = pop;
        }
    }
    map<string, int> capitals;

public:
    SingletonDatabase(SingletonDatabase const&) = delete;
    void operator=(SingletonDatabase const&) = delete;
    static SingletonDatabase& get()
    {
        static SingletonDatabase db;
        return db;
    }
    int get_population(const string& name)
    {
        return capitals[name];
    }

};

struct SingletonRecordFinder
{
    int total_population(vector<string> names)
    {
        int result{0};
        for (auto& name : names)
        {
            result += SingletonDatabase::get().get_population(name);
        }
        return result;
    }
};

TEST(RECORDFINDERTESTS, SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST)
{
    SingletonRecordFinder rf;
    vector<string> names = { "Germany", "Tokyo"};
    int tp = rf.total_population(names);
    EXPECT_EQ(25000000+140000000, tp);
}

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&ac,av);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

task.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\myProgram.exe",
                "-I",
                "C:/Boost/include/boost-1_73",
                "-I",
                "C:/GoogleTest/googletest/googletest/include",
                "-I",
                "C:/GoogleTest/googletest/bin",
                "-L",
                "C:/GoogleTest/googletest/lib/Debug"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GCC",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/GoogleTest/googletest/**"

            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\myProgram.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have compiled Google Test with MSVC compiler but you are compiling your application with GCC (why?). That is not going to work. Use the same toolset for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [rveerd's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64554687/how-to-include-google-test-in-visual-studio-code-msvc-project/64646707#comment114184138_64554687) comment i finnaly figured it out:

I recompiled the googletest library the correct way with the mingw compiler, how to shown in the picture below:

[GoogleTest MinGW compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PFjT.png)

Then i altered my files as followed.

In the launch.json file i referenced the preLaunchTask to my "mingw build"  This makes it so when launching the debugger first this build task wil be executed. Be sure to correctly reference your program.exe to your launch.json that is created on the build task. This will run the debugger using that given executable.

I also added my task.json with the needed args to link myprogram to the build google test libraries and the include directories.

I can now build with CTRL + SHIFT + B and run the program in debug with F5. This alle with the google test library included in the project!

Files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#define GTEST_LANG_CXX 1
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
using namespace std;

class SingletonDatabase
{
    SingletonDatabase()
    {
        cout << "INIT DATABASE\n";
        ifstream ifs("capticals.txt");
        string s, s2;

        while (getline(ifs, s))
        {
            getline(ifs, s2);
            int pop = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s2);
            capitals[s] = pop;
        }
    }
    map<string, int> capitals;

public:
    SingletonDatabase(SingletonDatabase const&) = delete;
    void operator=(SingletonDatabase const&) = delete;
    static SingletonDatabase& get()
    {
        static SingletonDatabase db;
        return db;
    }
    int get_population(const string& name)
    {
        return capitals[name];
    }

};

struct SingletonRecordFinder
{
    int total_population(vector<string> names)
    {
        int result{0};
        for (auto& name : names)
        {
            result += SingletonDatabase::get().get_population(name);
        }
        return result;
    }
};

TEST(RECORDFINDERTESTS, SINGLETONTOTALPOPTEST)
{
    SingletonRecordFinder rf;
    vector<string> names = { "Germany", "Tokyo"};
    int tp = rf.total_population(names);
    EXPECT_EQ(25000000+140000000, tp);
}

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&ac,av);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

TASK.JSON

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "mingw build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\myProgram.exe",
                "-I",
                "C:/Boost/include/boost-1_73",
                "-I",
                "C:/googletest/googletest/include",
                "-L",
                "C:/googletest/googletest/lib",
                "-lgtest",
                "-lgtest_main"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
      
    ]
}
```

LAUNCH.JSON

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/myProgram.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "mingw build"
        }
    ]
}
```

C_CPP_PROPERTIES.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GCC",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "g++-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to -I (capital "eye") which says where to find the include files, you need a -L which says where to find the libaries.

Comment: My gtest_maind.lib files are located in C:\GoogleTest\googletest\lib\Debug I've added the task.json file: with "-L", "C:/GoogleTest/googletest/lib/Debug". But the same errors stil occur. I've tried with the -l gtest options and without. Stil the same.

Comment: My gtest_maind.lib and other lib files are located in C:\GoogleTest\googletest\lib\Debug.